# Why are the images not rendered properly while using material design 2.0.0 beta8?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2, angular-directive, angular-components

[This is how the images are rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqFAP.png)

I have already tried going through the documentation.
I am adding my code snippet too.

```
    <div class="container"
     fxLayout="column"
     fxLayoutGap="10px">

<md-list fxFlex>
  <md-list-item *ngFor="let dish of dishes">
    <img md-list-avatar src={{dish.image}} alt={{dish.name}}>
    <h1 md-line> {{dish.name}} </h1>
    <p md-line>
      <span> {{dish.description}} </span>
    </p>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>

</div>
```

Comment: `dish.image` variable could have wrong URL, check console/network tab

Comment: Thank You for suggesting something but there is no problem with the URL's. I think it's something with the version of 'angular material'

Comment: You are missing " " around your src= statements, if an image name has a space in it, that's going to mess things up I reckon.

Comment: TS doesn't require " " around src. Also there are no spaces

Comment: Update : I have got the correct answer by hit and trial of a few possible cases. There was some problem with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try following this should work considering you are sending a correct path

```
<md-list fxFlex>
  <md-list-item *ngFor="let dish of dishes">
    <img md-list-avatar [src]="dish.image" alt={{dish.name}}>
    <h1 md-line> {{dish.name}} </h1>
    <p md-line>
      <span> {{dish.description}} </span>
    </p>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```